# Css - extend sub menu div to parent?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with sub items. I can display submenu full witdh but inside submenu div content stracthed some point and i couldn't make it full witdh. I explain it at this picture on bottom. So sub menu div needs to extend other col on left side.

```css
.menu {
 list-style:none;
}
.item {
 display:inline-block;
 height:50px;
}
.item a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:20px;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#333333;
 font-size:14px;
 border-right:1px #ebedf0 solid;
}
.item a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:#f0f3f7;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
 background-color:#f0f3f7;
}
.item .sub {
 display:none;
 width: 100%;
 padding:0 1000em;
 margin:0 -1000em;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#f0f3f7;
 z-index:1;
 box-shadow:0px 6px 20px -8px #999999;
}
.item:hover .sub {
 margin-top:2px;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 logo">
     <a href="index.php" title="Anasayfa"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="170" height="55" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 visible-lg hidden-xs">
     
     <ul class="menu">
      <li class="item">
       <a href="index.php" title="Anasayfa">Anasayfa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
       <a href="#" title="Kategoriler">Kategoriler <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
       <div class="sub">
        <div style="width:1000px;">
         cat
                                </div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
       <a href="#" title="Geliştirme">Geliştirme</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
       <a href="#" title="Dosyalar">Dosyalar <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
       <div class="sub">
                            dosyalar
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 visible-lg">
     Search
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly, the code below should solve your issue.  The padding and margin values on your .item .sub were the culprit.  I also added the left: 0px to left align it.

```
.item .sub {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f0f3f7;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px -8px #999999;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Still nothing changes. sub menu div needs to start from bottom of logo col.

Comment: using the code that you provided, it appears to work properly.. see this dojo [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/ubAKO).  Maybe there's an issue in some CSS that you didn't include in this example?